# How can I preselect a generated radio button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Website is meant to have several carts per user and they are listed and updated via AngularJS like this:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="cart in carts|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
    <td>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="form['cart_id']"
               ng-value="cart.cart.cart_id" />
    </td>
    <td>{{cart.cart.alias}}</td>
    <td>{{cart.cart.description}}</td>
    <td>{{cart.cart.created}}</td>
</tr>
```

When I add another cart in `$scope.carts` it gets updated pretty well, but I am not able to let the new cart be preselected when it is shown.

I tried using adding `ng-checked=true` which did not work, adding an ID and setting `.attr('checked','checked')` in JQuery, but the element is not known at that moment.

I am using Angular 1.2.22, JQuery 1.9.0 and Bootstrap 2.3.2. So I am well aware it's pretty outdated, but as I am new here, I am not able to change it. Yet.

Comment: Did you check if the document was ready before executing the JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio buttons are pre-selected by setting their model to the defined value. To select the last item in the `carts` array:

```
var last = $scope.carts.length-1;
$scope.form.cart_id = $scope.carts[last].cart_id;
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<input type=radio>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Comment: Thank you I've been on the documentations site the whole day yesterday. Maybe I just got blind of it. Thanks to your help and my rest it works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

Use value prop to make radio preselected, like: `value=<value of ng-model variable which you want to get preselected>`

Refer to this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D